# Unable to open windows disks in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot

I have done a manual dual boot of linux 14.04 lts windows 8.1.
i created 3 drives mainly swap, home and another normal ext 4 drive.all the 3 drives together occupied 80 gb or so.
however after installation i am unable to open the my normal windows drives through ubuntu like local disk c etc...
the following error message appears...

```
Unable to access “New Volume”
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/murali/New Volume: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda5" "/media/murali/New Volume"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shu**tdown**
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

---

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot mount NTFS partition in Ubuntu 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/291864/cannot-mount-ntfs-partition-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 0):

This means that Windows marked these partitions as "probably damaged", and Linux will not mount them to avoid further damaging them.
You could override this check, but, better, boot into Windows and run Disc Check on those partitions. After that, shut Windows down with menu-shutdown, no fancy options, no hibernate.

Comment: Partitions are not really damaged in any way, most likely

Answer (score 0):

Just open a terminal and type the following command:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda5
```

This will solve the problem temporarily, for permanent fix open Windows , go to **power options and system settings** and uncheck **Turn on fast startup**.